# How to load a lottie-web animation directly with the JSON content without providing a path

Tags: lottie

I would like to create a single animated web-component without any external dependency.

Until now, when I use lottie, I provide a path to the lottie JSON

```
lottie.loadAnimation({
  [...]
  path: 'data.json' // the path to the animation json
});
```

But I need to package my web-component without external reference to a JSON.

My first idea is to put the JSON content into a blob and then use `URL.createObjectURL()` to create a local URL.

---

Is there more direct way to create an animation already having loaded the JSON ?

Answer (score -1):

Bodymovin has an option to export a Standalone animation file.
This will bundle your json and the player itself into one js file you can use.

See: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/wiki/Composition-Settings

Comment: It's indeed a solution.
But I would prefer to keep the player and the JSON separated, as I might have multiple animation in the same page.